# Google Admin Console - Log IP Addresses

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have created a project for GAM using their instructions and it works. I can access our G Suite and print OS and User information to csv on the command line.

I need to do something very similar, but I need the Chrome devices' IP address at the time it last logged in.

I have found a 'LAN IP Address' under each devices 'System and Activity Troubleshooting' section, but our devices do not seem to be logging this information.

I would certainly provide example of what I have tried to far, but I am not sure where to begin. My objectives are:

- Start logging the wireless LAN IP address each time a device logs into G Suite
- Be able to access that information on a command line similar to GAM functionality

If anyone can offer guidance I would be very grateful. I thought the Login Report API would help, but it only logs the internet address from the device to Google, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you referring to [Admin console audit log](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579579?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes, in part. I thought the Audit Log would give me the private, local IP address of each device that checks into G Suite (for Education), but that does not appear to be the case. The Local IP address that I can find is under Device Management > Chrome Devices > select a Device > System and Activity Troubleshooting. But, the field is blank for all of our Devices. Essentially I do not care how it happens, as long as I can begin to pull Chromebook IP information in an automated fashion, similar to what GAM allows on a command line.